# Magento 2 : Search, Mini cart and menu disappear from website

Tags: magento-2.1.7, header

I have Magento 2.1.7 store and it was working properly since last 3 months. But yesterday Search, Mini cart and menu disappear from website ,there is no error log for this.
I didn't find how to fix the issue.

Can anyone suggest what should I do to find out the error?

Comment: You flushed the cache?

Comment: @Haim, Yes, I did.

Comment: Did something change in the server?

Comment: Is server changes reflect this?

Comment: If nothing changed - nothing breaks. *Something* changed

Comment: How to figure out that?

Comment: There is an warning in system.log file, "main.CRITICAL: Warning: imageftbbox(): Could not find/open font in /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php on line 506 in magento2"

Comment: Try disabling the module locally as follows

`bin/magento module:disable Magento_Captcha` - see if that helps